# Friendly id in nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, friendly-id

I'm using friendly_id to generate URLs on my rails application.

I have to following model organization :

Ad :

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :area
 ...
```

Area :

```
class Area < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :ads
 validates :name
 ...
```

And the following function in Ad model to generate the URL for each Ad :

```
friendly_id :title_and_title, use: :slugged 

def title_and_title
 "classified ads france #{title}"
end
```

What I'd like to do is to add the **area name** in the URL. 
How could I do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
def title_and_title
  self.area.name
end
```

To get the name for it's parent.

Comment: def title_and_title
      "classified ads france #{title} #{self.area.name}"
    end